# How do I integrate wikipedia data to my local mediawiki?

Tags: mediawiki, wikipedia, wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api

I have set up a local mediawiki instance. It's running fine. Now I want the entire wikipedia locally.

I found this dump : https://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiki/latest/

Which files do I download?

Once downloaded, how do I set up push the data to mediawiki?

I used : https://github.com/rlewkowicz/docker-mediawiki-stack to set up MediaWiki on my AWS instance.

My end-target is to use the Wikipedia Search API from my AWS instance, instead of the publicly available endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

The Wikipedia dump is huge and your installation will probably crash. If you want to try anyway, [mwdumper](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:MWDumper) is probably your best bet for the xml files. It's not very well maintained. I don't think there is any out-of-the box solution to automatically push updates.

Comment: Hi, There are a lot of xml files in that dump. Which ones do I download??

Comment: Depends on what you want. If you use the timestamp-based URL (such as https://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiki/20170520/ ) you get some info about what is what.